# ERC721 - How is gas worked out with TokenID?

Tags: gas, gas-estimate, erc-721

ERC721 - I have minted a tokenid (tokenid=444) and my account owns it. When I try and transfer it, I get this message stating the gas cost is the normally calculated one and the total cost has the tokenid added (which is arbitrary). How is that worked out?

I am just trying to assign a unique token ID to my wallet address which could then be used to tag rare items (eg rare art). I am using this  ERC721 [contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol). I did not expect the total cost to be related to the tokenid.

[image: Metamask]

Answer (score 1):

This is a UX bug. Please report it to MetaMask. And if you can please post a comment link here so I can give you a thumbs up.

Here’s what’s happening. MetaMask understands ERC-20 just enough. And it does not yet understand ERC-721. So it thinks your transaction applies to a ERC-20 token.

The ERC-20 transfer function is similar to ERC-721 except that instead of the tokenid there is a value parameter. So MetaMask assumes you are transferring 444 value plus gas costs.

Of course now that you know this you will know what you are looking at next time you see the dialog. But for others it is very confusing and the Ux should be improved.

Comment: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/6174